# Segmentation fault in command-line utility for mounting network shares

Tags: objective-c, macos, gdb, segmentation-fault, samba

I have the following code, and I keep getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I had a more complex copy of this code posted, but I boiled the problem to the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <NetFS/NetFS.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL * share = [NSURL URLWithString: @"smb://192.168.0.100/lib"];
        NSURL * path = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/Users/bogdan/Network/Library/"];
        CFURLRef share2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) share;
        CFURLRef path2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) path;

        NetFSMountURLSync(share2, path2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is with the "NetFSMountURLSync" line, but I can not figure out what the issue is. I think I am using it right, I removes all of the options I can. After running this, the share gets mounted, but right after that I get the error.

Comment: Can you copy-paste your CLI input and output? How are you running the executable?

Comment: Have you tried running your executable manually from GDB or LLDB, without Xcode?

Comment: Input: ./mysmbmount smb://192.168.0.101/lib /Users/bogdan/Network/lib/ Bunzilla2

Output: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: The network share is mounted after, and everything works properly. So the error does not brake the functionality, but I am not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: Here is the output from GDB: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff8f8cdfe9 in NetFSMountURLSync (). I'll add it to the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Got IT! Apparently, even if I do not care about the returned mountpoint, I still have to pass a variable to the function so it can store it there. This code works:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

@autoreleasepool {

    NSURL * share = [NSURL URLWithString: @"smb://192.168.0.100/lib"];
    NSURL * path = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/Users/bogdan/Network/Library/"];
    CFURLRef share2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) share;
    CFURLRef path2 = (__bridge CFURLRef) path;
    CFArrayRef mountpoints = NULL;

    NetFSMountURLSync(share2, path2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mountpoints);
}
return 0;
}
```